# AS2 Play Movie Clip OnMouseUp not working

Tags: flash

My plan is to initiate part of a movie clip on mouseDown and complete it only when mouseUp has been initiated. This is for a drag and drop onto a UI element that appears only when mouse down is initiated.

I have managed to do this with the following AS2 on the first frame on the timeline:

```
stop();
slide_mc.stop();
button_btn.onPress = function() {
    slide_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);
};

button_btn.onRelease = function() {
    slide_mc.gotoAndPlay(8);
};
```

This works well for the first time, but after that it does not recognise my mouseDown, only my mouseUp.

Ive have murdered google in trying to search for a similar problem!

I would be so grateful if someone could help!

Comment: looks ok to me - try swapping the two functions to test it...

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to solve my problem, and yes it was a bit of a noobie mistake.

Basically I told the slide_mc to stop(); when the .swf opened. I also had a stop command on the first frame of the slide_mc. Basically this stopped the first half of the animation from commencing after it had been used once.